# Excel date conversion to day of the week: not working after 1 row

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I want to get days of the month corresponding to each particular dates in a column in Excel (Note that I am using the web version of office Excel).

The formula `=TEXT(A2,"dddd")` works correctly for the first row and then when applied to the later rows does not perform as needed. It returns the same date and not the weekday. I have checked the format of the cells, and it is all sent to *General*.

See the attached image for reference, the formula worked in `C2`, and not after that.

Note: I have inserted a table for the required range.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not Recognizing `d/m/yyyy`

For cell `A2` you can use this formula instead (in cell `C2`):

`d/m/yyyy` (Your Case)

```
=TEXT(DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2,4))),VALUE(MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,FIND("/",A2,4)-FIND("/",A2)-1)),VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1))),"dddd")
```

`m/d/yyyy` (Someone else might need this.)

```
=TEXT(DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2,4))),VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1)),VALUE(MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,FIND("/",A2,4)-FIND("/",A2)-1))),"dddd")
```